# C++ TCP Client Send Immidiately

Tags: c, tcp

Is there any way to get a C TCP Client to send its messages immidiately after the socket descriptor has been written to?

I have tried setting `TCP_NODELAY`

Comment: On what platform? TCP implementations varies. I guess TCP_NODELAY should be enough on Linux...

Comment: @lvella It is Linux.

Comment: Define 'immediately'. Even the Nagle algorithm only delays things by 200ms. What problem are you actually experiencing?

Comment: @EJP Since it is on the same system I am not worried about dropped messages.  I want to avoid having to delimit the messages in any way on the receiving side, and I can do this if I know every packet sent contains only one complete message.

Comment: No you can't. There are no messages, or message boundaries, in TCP. You have delimit your messages, or provide length-words, etc. And there is never a need to worry about dropped messages in TCP.

Comment: @EJP That's what I was thinking.  So I guess I'm off to implement fixed length delimited messages.